# How to init view model only once in SwiftUI (iOS 13)?

Tags: ios, swiftui, combine

I have a MainView and a ContainerView that takes 3 different viewmodels..

I'm making service queries in the viewmodels of the subviews (Container View). These queries are repeated when the parent view changes. I don't want it to be repeated.

ContainerViewModel is constantly inited from scratch every time "showHeader" and tab changes. How can I prevent this?

(My project supports iOS 13, I cannot use `StateObject`.)

```
struct MainView: View {
    
    // MARK: - Properties
    
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: MainViewModel
    @State private var selectedCategory: CategoryType = .first
    
    // MARK: - Body
    
    var body: some View {
        HeaderView() { category in
            selectedCategory = category
        }
        TabView(selection: $selectedCategory) {
            ContainerView(viewModel: ContainerViewModel(selectedCategory: .first))
                .tag(CategoryType.first)
            ContainerView(viewModel: ContainerViewModel(selectedCategory: .second))
                .tag(CategoryType.second)
            ContainerView(viewModel: ContainerViewModel(selectedCategory: .third))
                .tag(CategoryType.third)
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct ContainerView: View {
    
    // MARK: - Properties
    
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: ContainerViewModel
    @State private var showHeader = true
    
    // MARK: - Body
    
    var body: some View {
        if showHeader {
            HeaderView() { category in
                selectedCategory = category
            }
        }
        TabView(selection: $selectedCategory) {
            ContainerView(showHeader: $showHeader)
            .environmentObject(ContainerViewModel(selectedCategory: .first))
            ContainerView(showHeader: $showHeader)
            .environmentObject(ContainerViewModel(selectedCategory: .second))
            ContainerView(showHeader: $showHeader)
            .environmentObject(ContainerViewModel(selectedCategory: .third))
        }
    }
}

class ContainerViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var selectedCategory: CategoryType
    
    init(selectedCategory: CategoryType) {
        self.selectedCategory = selectedCategory
        // Network requests transactions...
    }
}
```

Comment: use StateObject var  instead of Published var

Comment: @YodagamaHeshan I can't use stateobject to support ios 13. :/

Comment: You have to use State, the limitation is that in the View where the State is you won’t see changes only the subviews with EnvironmentObject

Comment: Would you please tell me what is HeaderView()

Comment: I think you have too many view models created. In the main view you have 1(environment) and you create one for each containerView. Then each container view has 1(environment but created each time view is reloaded) and create 3 new for each sub view… Try to rethink where should be declared your models and how to pass them to du view (environment or observable object) and who they belong to (app, main view ?)

Comment: There are a couple of issues with the construction. The headerView does not need to set the category, because the tab view already has binding to the selectedCategory. Another, have a single source of truth, especially in SwiftUI where state controls the UI directly. Think of where you'd like to place selectedCategory. If you ask me, it should be in a separate model and you should observe changes and mutate it separately. It would be easier to scale your code

Comment: In SwiftUI the View struct plus property wrappers is equivalent to a view model you don't need your own objects that will just lead to consistency bugs.